# Historial de pagos

Tags: php, php7, php5

hola estoy tratando de realizar un historial de pagos donde se le informa al usuario la fecha el valor de la cuota que de pagar y cuantas cuotas debe de pagar, aparte de ello se le da a conocer si es mensual, quincenal o semanal, el calculo lo hace bien, el numero de cuotas igual pero no logro realizar estas condiciones: si el pago es quincenal debe ser cada 8 dias a partir de la fecha_reg , si es quincenal debe ser cada 15 y cada 30, y si es mensual cada 30 dias pues me devuelve esto

```
fecha inicio : 2023-05-31 

Pago 1: Fecha: 01/06/2023 - Cuota: 53.333
Pago 2: Fecha: 16/06/2023 - Cuota: 53.333
Pago 3: Fecha: 01/07/2023 - Cuota: 53.333
Pago 4: Fecha: 16/07/2023 - Cuota: 53.333
Pago 5: Fecha: 31/07/2023 - Cuota: 53.333
Pago 6: Fecha: 15/08/2023 - Cuota: 53.333
```

no arranca bien la fecha

este es el codigo que escribi para ello pero necesito que arranque con las especificaciones que menciono

```
     <?php
// Obtener los valores de la fila actual de la tabla
$monto = $fila['monto'];
$total = $fila['total'];
$cuota = $fila['cuotas']; // Valor de la cuota obtenido de la base de datos
$plazo = $fila['plazo']; // Número de meses obtenido de la base de datos
$metodo = $fila['metodo'];

// Determinar el período de pago en función del método seleccionado
if ($metodo == "Quincenal") {
    $periodoPago = 15; // El pago se realiza cada 15 días
} elseif ($metodo == "Mensual") {
    $periodoPago = 30; // El pago se realiza cada mes
} elseif ($metodo == "Semanal") {
    $periodoPago = 7; // El pago se realiza cada semana
} else {
    $periodoPago = 1; // Si no se especifica un método válido, se realiza un pago diario
}

// Obtener la fecha de inicio y ajustarla al siguiente mes (el día 15)
$fechaReg = $fila['fecha_reg'];
$fechaInicio = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $fechaReg)->format('d/m/Y');
$mesInicio = date('m', strtotime($fechaReg));
$anioInicio = date('Y', strtotime($fechaReg));

// Obtener el próximo mes
$mesSiguiente = intval($mesInicio) + 1;
if ($mesSiguiente > 12) {
    $mesSiguiente = 1;
    $anioInicio++;
}

$fechaInicio = sprintf('%02d', $mesSiguiente) . '/01/' . $anioInicio; // Cambiar '15' a '01'

// Calcular el número total de pagos basado en el plazo y el período de pago
$numPagos = ceil($plazo * (30 / $periodoPago));

// Mostrar los pagos individualmente
$fechaPago = strtotime($fechaInicio); // Fecha inicial
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numPagos; $i++) {
    // Ajustar las fechas de pago quincenal
    if ($metodo == "Quincenal") {
        $diasAjuste = ($i - 1) * $periodoPago;
        $fechaPago = strtotime("+" . $diasAjuste . " days", strtotime($fechaInicio));
    } elseif ($metodo == "Mensual") {
        $fechaPago = strtotime("+" . ($i - 1) . " month", strtotime($fechaInicio));
    } elseif ($metodo == "Semanal") {
        $fechaPago = strtotime("+" . ($i - 1) * $periodoPago . " days", strtotime($fechaInicio));
    }

    $fechaPagoFormat = date('d/m/Y', $fechaPago);
    $montoPago = $cuota;
    echo "Pago $i: Fecha: $fechaPagoFormat - Cuota: $montoPago<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? Pulsa en [edit] y agrega una lista de fechas esperadas partiendo del día `2023-05-31`. No se entiende, por ejemplo, si las cuotas deben empezar ese mismo día o `N` días después de esa fecha según el método que aplique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este programa puede llegar a ser complejo si le empiezas a meter más validaciones o funcionalidad, por ejemplo: considerar cuando un día de pago cae feriado o fin de semana. O si los rangos de fecha no siempre son 15 y 30, por ejemplo pagar los días 4 y 19 del mes.

Entonces para ir creciendo (escalando) la aplicación, este es un muy buen ejemplo para usar la programación Orientada a Objetos.

```php
<?php
class Pagos {
    private $cliente;
    private $monto;
    private $cuota = 1;
    private $fecha_reg;
    
    function __construct($cliente, $monto, $fecha_reg) { 
        $this->cliente   = $cliente;
        $this->monto     = $monto;
        $this->fecha_reg = $fecha_reg;
    }
    
    public static function get_next_day($start_day, $method='diario') {
        $cdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $start_day);
        while(true) {
            yield str_replace('31', '30', $cdate->format('Y-m-d'));
            if($method == 'semanal') {
                $cdate->modify('+7 day');
            } elseif($method == 'quincenal') {
                if($cdate->format('d') > '15') { // 28, 30
                    $cdate->modify('+3 day');
                    $cdate->setDate($cdate->format('Y'), $cdate->format('m'), '15');
                } else {
                    $cdate->modify('last day of this month');
                }
            } elseif($method == 'mensual') {
                $cdate->modify('+28 day');
                $cdate->modify('last day of this month');
            } else { // $method == 'dia' o sin especificar
                $cdate->modify('+1 day');
            }
        }
    }
    
    public function set_cuota($cuota) {
        $this->cuota = $cuota;
    }
    
    public function set_num_pagos($num_pagos) {
        $this->cuota = $this->monto / $num_pagos;
    }
    
    public function imprimir_cuotas($metodo) {
        $total = $this->monto;
        $cuota = $this->cuota;
        $calendar = self::get_next_day($this->fecha_reg, $metodo);
        $i = 0;
        while(round($total, 3) > 0.000) {
            if($total - $cuota < 0) { 
                $cuota = $total; 
            }
            $total -= $cuota;
            echo 'Pago ' . ++$i . ': ' . $calendar->current() . ' - $' . $cuota . PHP_EOL;
            $calendar->next();
        }
    }
}
```

Suponiendo que "Juan" debe `$910.82` y empezará a pagar desde el `30-jun-2023`. Se crea el objeto `$cl1` para este cliente:

```php
$cl1 = new Pagos('Juan', 910.82, '2023-06-30');
```

Ejemplo 1: Las cuotas serán de `$165.35` `quincenal` hasta que termine.

```php
$cl1->set_cuota(165.35);
$cl1->imprimir_cuotas('quincenal');
```

Salida:

```
Pago 1: 2023-06-30 - $165.35
Pago 2: 2023-07-15 - $165.35
...
Pago 6: 2023-09-15 - $84.07
```

Ejemplo 2: Dividir en exactamente `12` pagos `mensuales`:

```php
$cl1->set_num_pagos(12);
$cl1->imprimir_cuotas('mensual');
```

Salida:

```
Pago 1: 2023-06-30 - $75.901666666667
Pago 2: 2023-07-30 - $75.901666666667
...
Pago 12: 2024-05-30 - $75.901666666667
```

Comment: Muchas gracias puedes ayudarme con algo mas?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias cosas que se pueden mejorar en tu código.

1. Para evitar tantos `if` a la hora de determinar cada cuantos días se aplicará el descuento, puedes crear un array asociativo donde, por cada método pones el valor que aplica. Luego, usando fusión de null, obtendrás el valor, o bien `1` que es el valor por defecto.
2. Das demasiadas vueltas para ir mostrando las fechas en que se cobrarán las cuotas. Considera usar objetos `DateTime` y sus derivados: `DatePeriod` y `DateInterval` para este caso.

   La lógica es muy simple:

   a. Creas un objeto `DateTime` con la fecha inicial

   b. Clonas ese objeto y lo modificas, añadiéndole un intervalo en meses del valor que haya en `$plazo`.

   c. Creas un objeto `DatePeriod` entre las fechas creadas en `a` y en `b`, con un `DateInterval` según los días correspondientes al método. Ese objeto `DatePeriod` no es otra cosa ¡que todas las fechas comprendidas en ese rango que podrás recorrer en un bucle e imprimirlas!. Revisa los enlaces a la documentación, al final de la respuesta para que entiendas cómo funciona. Aquí he asumido que la fecha inicial no debe comprenderse en el período, por eso he pasado la bandera `DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE`. Si debe ser de otro modo simplemente cambia eso.

El código sería así más o menos, usaré valores a mano y pongo comentario en cada línea para que se entienda lo que hago en cada punto:

```
$metodo="Quincenal";
$plazo=3;
$cuota=53.333;
$fechaReg = '2023-05-31';//$fila['fecha_reg'];
# Array asociativo con los métodos de pago
$metodos=array("Quincenal"=>15, "Mensual"=>30, "Semanal"=>7);
# Determinamos dias de pago usando fusión de null
# Asignamos 1 si no se encuentra ningún valor
$diasPago = $metodos[$metodo] ?? 1;
# Objeto DateTime con la fecha de inicio
$fechaInicio=new DateTime($fechaReg);
# Clonamos la fecha de inicio
$fechaFin=clone $fechaInicio;
# ... y le agregamos los meses de $plazo
$fechaFin->add(new DateInterval("P{$plazo}M"));
# Este es el intervalo para el período, tomado de $metodos
$interval = new DateInterval("P{$diasPago}D");
# Esto contendrá todas las fechas en el período
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod($fechaInicio, $interval ,$fechaFin,DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
$i=1;
# Recorremos el período e imprimimos sus fechas
foreach ($datePeriod as $date) {
    printf("Pago: %d Fecha: %s - Cuota: %s \n",$i++,$date->format('Y-m-d'),$cuota);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Pago: 1 Fecha: 2023-06-15 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 2 Fecha: 2023-06-30 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 3 Fecha: 2023-07-15 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 4 Fecha: 2023-07-30 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 5 Fecha: 2023-08-14 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 6 Fecha: 2023-08-29 - Cuota: 53.333
```

---

Probemos ahora con otros valores:

#### Mensual

```
$metodo="Mensual";
$plazo=3;
$cuota=53.333;
```

**Salida:**

```
Pago: 1 Fecha: 2023-06-30 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 2 Fecha: 2023-07-30 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 3 Fecha: 2023-08-29 - Cuota: 53.333
```

---

#### Semanal

```
$metodo="Semanal";
$plazo=3;
$cuota=53.333;
```

**Salida:**

```
Pago: 1  Fecha: 2023-06-07 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 2  Fecha: 2023-06-14 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 3  Fecha: 2023-06-21 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 4  Fecha: 2023-06-28 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 5  Fecha: 2023-07-05 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 6  Fecha: 2023-07-12 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 7  Fecha: 2023-07-19 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 8  Fecha: 2023-07-26 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 9  Fecha: 2023-08-02 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 10 Fecha: 2023-08-09 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 11 Fecha: 2023-08-16 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 12 Fecha: 2023-08-23 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 13 Fecha: 2023-08-30 - Cuota: 53.333
```

---

#### "fake", asume valor por defecto

```
$metodo="fake";
$plazo=1;
$cuota=53.333;
```

**Salida:**

```
Pago: 1  Fecha: 2023-06-01 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 2  Fecha: 2023-06-02 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 3  Fecha: 2023-06-03 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 4  Fecha: 2023-06-04 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 5  Fecha: 2023-06-05 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 6  Fecha: 2023-06-06 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 7  Fecha: 2023-06-07 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 8  Fecha: 2023-06-08 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 9  Fecha: 2023-06-09 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 10 Fecha: 2023-06-10 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 11 Fecha: 2023-06-11 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 12 Fecha: 2023-06-12 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 13 Fecha: 2023-06-13 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 14 Fecha: 2023-06-14 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 15 Fecha: 2023-06-15 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 16 Fecha: 2023-06-16 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 17 Fecha: 2023-06-17 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 18 Fecha: 2023-06-18 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 19 Fecha: 2023-06-19 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 20 Fecha: 2023-06-20 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 21 Fecha: 2023-06-21 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 22 Fecha: 2023-06-22 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 23 Fecha: 2023-06-23 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 24 Fecha: 2023-06-24 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 25 Fecha: 2023-06-25 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 26 Fecha: 2023-06-26 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 27 Fecha: 2023-06-27 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 28 Fecha: 2023-06-28 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 29 Fecha: 2023-06-29 - Cuota: 53.333 
Pago: 30 Fecha: 2023-06-30 - Cuota: 53.333
```

---

#### Enlaces a la documentación

Cada enlace tiene a su vez enlaces a los diferentes métodos de estas clases, con ejemplos de código.

1. La clase [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)
2. La clase [`DatePeriod`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php)
3. La clase [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php)